# Compare String in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, compare

In jquery ajax function I recive to the server "true" or "false" strings. Then I only wnat know result but only get false in if condition.

```
 $.ajax({
    ...
        success: function(result) {
              if(result == "true"){   // false???????
                    alert('true');
                } else {
                    alert('false');
                }
             }
        })
    ...
```

---

```
$.ajax({
...
    success: function(result) {
          var result2 = String(result); 
          alert(result2);          // true
          alert(typeof result2);   // String
          alert(typeof "true");    // String
          if(result2 == "true"){   // false???????
                alert('true');
            } else {
                alert('false');
            }
         }
    })
...
```

...

Somebody can help me?

Comment: If your interpreter says that `result == "true"` is `false` then `result` is not `"true"`. Simple as that. You might want to check if your assumption of what `result` is, are really holding. Try `console.log(result)`.

Comment: Are you sure result contains "true" ?

Comment: you're using jQuery, and jQuery uses "smart guesses" sometimes to figure the result type. try `result === true`. It might have turned into boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be line breaks or extra spaces in "result".

Comment: Prize for you! I only looking for problem in JS, but I was using println() function instead print() to response in java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,

An empty string, null, 0 and undefined are all false

`result2==="true"` is a better test

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VFSq4/)

Answer (score 0):

use trim() function...

e.g:

$.ajax({

...

```
success: function(result) {
      var result2 = String(result.trim()); 
      alert(result2);          // true
      alert(typeof result2);   // String
      alert(typeof "true");    // String
      if(result2 == "true"){   // true
            alert('true');
        } else {
            alert('false');
        }
     }
})
```

...